# Android NDK - get touch input

Tags: c++, c, android-ndk

In SDL getting any type of input is really easy:

```
SDL_Event event;
while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
   ...
}
```

On the other hand In Android NDK looks similar (this code is from [googlesamples/android-ndk/native-activity](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-activity)):

```
static int32_t engine_handle_input(struct android_app* app, AInputEvent* event) {
    struct engine* engine = (struct engine*)app->userData;
    if (AInputEvent_getType(event) == AINPUT_EVENT_TYPE_MOTION) {
          ...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but I don't understand where is the call for `engine_handle_input`.

Is it done automatically after setting the callback `state->onInputEvent = engine_handle_input;`?

And if so isn't there an easier way for getting input (like in SDL)?

Comment: _"where is the call for engine_handle_input"_?  It's set as the `onInputEvent` callback on line 314: `state->onInputEvent = engine_handle_input;`  So the OS will call it if/when there are input events for your app.

Comment: So what to do if my main is in a Java class and I don't have `void android_main(struct android_app* state)`, therefore I don't have access to `state` and can't set the callback?

Comment: It's a bit unclear exactly what you're trying to achieve. Why can't you just use the normal way for Android apps to listen for touch events?

Comment: what is the normal way?

Comment: The normal way for a NativeActivity would probably be what you saw in the sample from Google. For Activities written in Java/Koltin you would register onTouchListeners on the Views you're interested in.

Comment: Yeah that worked! Thanks.